# Implicit class on Iterable of my type and its subtypes

Tags: scala, generics, dsl

I'm trying to learn good practices to create a DSL using the rich possibilities of Scala but I've faced the following problem : I'm unable to create an implicit class that applies to all subtypes of Iterable (arrays, lists,...) and that matches only subtypes of a specific type I defined (in the example: Fruit).
Here's what I've came up with so far (it's a simplified version of my code) :

```
sealed trait Fruit { // My main type
  type A <: Fruit
  def setSize(v: Int): Unit = this match {
    case multi: MultiFruit[_] => multi.foreach(_.setSize(v))
    case or: Orange => or.size = v
    case ap: Apple => ap.size = v
    case _ => throw new Exception
  }
}
case class MultiFruit[F <: Fruit](var l: List[F]) extends Fruit {
  type A = F
  def foreach[B](f: F => B) : Unit = l.foreach(f)
}
case class Orange(var size: Int) extends Fruit {
  type A = Orange
}
case class Apple(var size: Int) extends Fruit {
  type A = Apple
}
object Fruit {
  implicit class IterableFruit[F <: Fruit, I <: Iterable[F]](val ite: I) extends AnyVal {
    def setSize(v: Int): Unit = ite.foreach(_.setSize(v)) // Apply setSize on every Fruit of the iterable
    def ++[F2 <: Fruit, I2 <: Iterable[F2]](ite2: I2): MultiFruit[_ <: Fruit] = new MultiFruit[Fruit](ite.toList++ite2.toList)
  }
}
```

So here is my problem: when I try to run this

```
object Main {
  import Fruit._
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val oranges = Array.tabulate(5)(i => Orange(i*10))
    val apples = Array.tabulate(5)(i => Apple(i*10))
    oranges setSize 20 // setSize is not found, it doesn't match Iterable[Fruit]
    val or_ap = oranges ++ apples // ++ not found (the compiler wants to use the one defined in Array)
  }
}
```

My method setSize and ++ are not found.
What makes me even more confused is that my IDE (IntelliJ) founds the setSize method (and doesn't report any error) but the IDE thinks that the ++ is the one defined in Array and not in my implicit class.
I think my problem comes from the way I typed my IterableFruit class, but ressources I found on extension methods is very limited (and never really go in depth) and I can't figure out what's wrong.

**Edit:** 
Also, when I modified my implicit class to:

```
object Fruit {
  implicit class IterableFruit[F <: Fruit](val ite: Array[F]) extends AnyVal {
    def setSize(v: Int): Unit = ite.foreach(_.setSize(v)) // Apply setSize on every Fruit of the iterable
    def ++[F2 <: Fruit](ite2: Array[F2]): MultiFruit[_ <: Fruit] = new MultiFruit[Fruit](ite.toList++ite2.toList)
  }
}
```

Everything compiles, but now it obviously doesn't work if I try to use any other iterable but an array, so I think the issue indeed come from the way I use typing in the implicit class

Comment: It's not surprising that your `++` method isn't being used. The conversion will happen if your original class doesn't contain that method

Comment: Also, the simplified version of your code doesn't compile

Comment: Oh yes indeed, I modified the post it now compiles (I also added a main function), regarding the ++, do you mean that I should implement it in the Fruit trait ? Because by doing this wouldn't it only match on single object (Fruit) which has nothing to do with the Iterable matching ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by turning your Arrays into Iterables with `toIterable` (The `Array` does not extend `Iterable`, since it represents a built-in Java array):

```
val oranges = Array.tabulate(5)(i => Orange(i*10)).toIterable
```

And for your `++` method to work, you have to rename it to something else, like `+:+`. Currently, the compiler sees no reason to do the implicit conversion, since there's already a `concat`/`++` method on your `oranges` object.

Link to [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/2QFcKeCnSm6KtIVDxAYfQA)

Comment: Oh fine I was not aware that Array does not extends Iterable (which is a bit weird I think), yes indeed the compiler won't use an implicit if it does not need to thank you